# What exactly is the deal with oracle connection identifiers separated by a period

Tags: oracle, configuration, tnsnames

I've been wondering this for a while but since it hasn't come up much I've left it in the 'mysterious wizardy' column.

It seems to me that there is some sort of relationship between a connection identifier like ABC and ABC.DEFG and I don't quite get what it is.

For example, a machine I was setting up just now I was having problems with using the identfier ED2 even though in my tnsnames file I clearly had

```
EDC2 = (....)
```

This was copied and pasted from another computer which worked just fine.  However, doing tnsping EDC2 would fail to resolve until I changed it to say

```
EDC2.WORLD = (...)
```

at which point resolving to EDC2 started working.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The TNS alias in the tnsnames.ora file interacts with the parameter

```
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN
```

in the sqlnet.ora file.  If `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN` is set to WORLD, for example, then when you try to connect to an alias without a domain, the sqlnet.ora file tells Oracle to automatically append the domain before doing the lookup in the tnsnames.ora file.  If you try to connect to an alias with a domain, `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN` is ignored.

My general preference/ suggestion is to set `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN` to WORLD in the sqlnet.ora and specify EDC2.WORLD in the tnsnames.ora file.  That way, both the connect identifier EDC2 and EDC2.WORLD will work-- the former gets changed to the latter because of the `DEFAULT_DOMAIN` parameter.